# Repairing DBCC CHECKDB errors

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I ran a CHECKDB and it spit out the following errors

```
Msg 8928, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Object ID 302676176, index ID 1, partition ID 72057594076135424, alloc unit ID 72057594090225664 (type In-row data): Page (1:262631) could not be processed.  See other errors for details.
Msg 8976, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Table error: Object ID 302676176, index ID 1, partition ID 72057594076135424, alloc unit ID 72057594090225664 (type In-row data). Page (1:262631) was not seen in the scan although its parent (1:263401) and previous (1:262630) refer to it. Check any previous errors.
Msg 8944, Level 16, State 13, Line 1
Table error: Object ID 302676176, index ID 1, partition ID 72057594076135424, alloc unit ID 72057594090225664 (type In-row data), page (1:262631), row 95. Test (ColumnOffsets <= (nextRec - pRec)) failed. Values are 1730 and 45.
Msg 8944, Level 16, State 13, Line 1
Table error: Object ID 302676176, index ID 1, partition ID 72057594076135424, alloc unit ID 72057594090225664 (type In-row data), page (1:262631), row 95. Test (ColumnOffsets <= (nextRec - pRec)) failed. Values are 1730 and 45.
Msg 8978, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Table error: Object ID 302676176, index ID 1, partition ID 72057594076135424, alloc unit ID 72057594090225664 (type In-row data). Page (1:262640) is missing a reference from previous page (1:262631). Possible chain linkage problem.
Msg 8928, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Object ID 302676176, index ID 1, partition ID 72057594076135424, alloc unit ID 72057594090225664 (type In-row data): Page (1:3143601) could not be processed.  See other errors for details.
Msg 8976, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Table error: Object ID 302676176, index ID 1, partition ID 72057594076135424, alloc unit ID 72057594090225664 (type In-row data). Page (1:3143601) was not seen in the scan although its parent (1:3143681) and previous (1:3143600) refer to it. Check any previous errors.
Msg 8944, Level 16, State 13, Line 1
```

How to repair the consistency errors in the table?

Answer (score 0):

To me its more of index consistency issue, although you can try to drop and recreate the index ID=1 of object 302676176 (select object_name(302676176) will give you the table name).

2nd option is DBCC CHECKTABLE (,REPAIR_REBUILD)

3rd and last option is DBCC CHECKTABLE (,REPAIR_ALLOW_DATA_LOSS).